# Using ArcMap attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, attribute-table, features

I am new to ArcMap.

I work with with the attribute table, so I took data from the [Esri LULC](https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/landcover/) site converting it from raster to polygon.

What I want to do is combine all of the same data into 7 features.  I do not know how to explain it with words so a screenshot might help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Your Question body and title references to "attribute table" have nearly nothing to do with your task, making this vrey confusing. Please [Edit] the Question .

Answer (score 2):

You can check the "Create multipart features" option when creating your polygons using the [Raster to Polygon](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) tool

Alternatively, you can use the [Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool to create multipart features from your polygons.